# upgrade 20.04 to 21.04. Direct upgrade or from scratch?

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, 21.04

I have ubuntu 20.04 and I'm considering upgrading...
I remember a few years ago that I tried on another machine, and it just didn't work, I had to reinstall from 0.
Then on my next machine I had to use windows and just last year I came back to ubuntu.

Now, it's been a few years since then... it's still an issue or it it safe to upgrade directly?

Thanks

Comment: There is no tested, supported upgrade path directly from 20.04 to 21.04. Use the 21.04 installer's option to overwrite (not format-and-reinstall). Of course, Ubuntu 21.10 will be released *next week*.

Comment: Considering there is no longer a supported upgrade path from 20.04 to 21.04, I'd suggest a clean installation.

Comment: 21.04 and 21.10 are only supported for 9 months.  20.04 is supported for five years.  Just something to think about.

Comment: thanks a lot for your comments!

Comment: In theory yes it is safe (automatic testing occurs on all upgrade *supported* upgrade paths but major focus is made on 20.04 to 20.10 (ie next release) & will occur on 20.04 to 22.04.1 (in the future). Yes a minor test is one LTS (eg. 20.04 to 21.04) but that will receive less testing as it's outside the intended paths ... so yes it's possible & should work; but problems are more likely than 20.04->20.10 ot 20.04->22.04.

Comment: Direct upgrade is possible. But you should know  that you will loose LTS support of 5 (really 4) years of support. I'll recommend to stay on LTS.

Comment: Assuming you're talking about a desktop install, a faster approach, and my backup if I have issues with *release-upgrade* (*my goto if I'm time-limited too*) is to *upgrade via re-install* which is just a install without format. Your installed packages are noted; system directories erased; system installed & if internet is there the additional packages you had installed are added back (if available for new release in Ubuntu repositories). No user file is touched unless you formatted - the lack of format triggers this install.